# Is Shmuel (Amora) considered a Tanna by the Jerusalem Talmud?

Tags: tannaim, talmud-yerushalmi, amoroim

The Jerusalem Talmud [Berakhot.9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.9a.3?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=bi) (similarly Yevamot 9a or Sotah 16a) says it in the name of Tannayim:

> "**תני**
> יצאת בת קול ואמרה אלו ואלו דברי אלהים חיים
> אבל הלכה כדברי בית הלל.
> איכן יצאה בת קול רבי ביבי אמר בשם רבי יוחנן ביבנה יצאה בת קול:"

The Babylonian Talmud attributes the story to the Amorayim ([Eruvin.13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.13b.10?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he)):

> "**אָמַר רַבִּי אַבָּא אָמַר שְׁמוּאֵל:**
> שָׁלֹשׁ שָׁנִים נֶחְלְקוּ בֵּית שַׁמַּאי וּבֵית הִלֵּל, הַלָּלוּ אוֹמְרִים: הֲלָכָה כְּמוֹתֵנוּ, וְהַלָּלוּ אוֹמְרִים: הֲלָכָה כְּמוֹתֵנוּ. יָצְאָה בַּת קוֹל וְאָמְרָה: אֵלּוּ וָאֵלּוּ דִּבְרֵי אֱלֹהִים חַיִּים הֵן, וַהֲלָכָה כְּבֵית הִלֵּל."

Assuming this is the same statement, is Shmuel considered a Tanna by the JT?

Comment: Surely the same story could be repeated by many different people? There is quite a lot of different attribution between the JT and the BT.

Comment: See https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpagefeed.aspx?req=3278&pgnum=365 for a discussion about both of Shmuel can argue with a tana and that Shmuel authored the Tana Dbei Shmuel which organized braisos and toseftos. This would explain the Yerushalmi. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62094/which-amoraim-can-argue-on-tannaim